# CSS question: how to remove the border from an image in WordPress

Tags: css, border

I'd like to remove the border from an image in WordPress.

It's the latest default theme (twenty eleven?)

In another question on this, I saw a link to a page that said, to change the "border-width" value. So I searched for "border-width" and changed the px value to "0", but this didn't do the trick.

I'm a beginner, so if possible simple steps will help. E.g. "change *this* to *this*" or "add *this* in *this place* in the css"

The image I'd like to remove the border from is the signature at the bottom of this page: http://richardclunan.com/

There's also a border around the photo closer to the top of that page, which I can either keep or get rid of that border. If I get rid of it, then I'll probably add a border to the image itself, if it's easier to get rid of all borders in the css.

Thanks, Richard

Comment: do you have control of style.css and the html for the image?

Comment: I know where to go in my ftp to locate style.css, and I can edit it. I don't know where to find the html -- I'd need to figure that out, but I do have all access.

Comment: Go to the Home page under "Pages" in the admin panel, and edit the code as HTML.

Comment: I can't see where to edit the HTML -- if I go to 'Pages', I see this: https://skitch.com/richardclunan/fxi5f/dreamweaver -- am I in the right place?

Comment: Then the homepage is probably hard-coded somewhere in the theme. Try checking pages with `index` or `home` in the name in the theme editor.

Comment: Thanks for your help mopsled. I couldn't figure this out, so I went for PeeHaa's solution, changing all image borders in the css, and then I added back a border in Photoshop to one of the images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either change

```
border: 1px solid #DDD;
```

to

```
border: 0;
```

@ style.css line 935

But that will affect all images in that style.

If you don't want that you can add an extra class to the image, e.g. `no-border` and add:

```
#content .no-border { border: 0; }
```

in your stylesheet

Comment: Thanks for giving a per image approach too. I find it quite bad that the wordpress interface doesn't offer an easier way to disable the border on an image. Bit of a bug if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of all the borders by changing the this rule in style.css (line 935)

```
#content .gallery .gallery-icon img {/* Add fancy borders to all WordPress-added images but not things like badges and icons and the like */
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

to

```
#content .gallery .gallery-icon img {/* Add fancy borders to all WordPress-added images but not things like badges and icons and the like */
    border: 0;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

or you can inline the style on the image (see mopsled's post)

Answer (score 0):

.gallery a img { border: 0 !important; }